# How to store JSON data within a HTML/JS Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to output data from a local JSON file, however I'm pretty new to JSON so I'm a little confused.

Snippet of my HTML File

```
<html> etc....
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="target1"></div>
      <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

.JSON File

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "age": "20",
      "url": "facebook.com/alex"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom",
      "age": "25",
      "url": "facebook.com/tom"
    },
```

START OF JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
$.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}); //loads JSON file into the console


//Creates a table
function makeTable(rows, columns, target){

  let tbl = document.createElement("table");

//Loop to create the number of rows
  for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++){
    let newRow = tbl.insertRow();  // Create a new row in the table

//Creates number of columns
    for(let c = 0; c < columns; c++){
      let newCell = newRow.insertCell();  // Create new cell
      newCell.textContent = "Row " + (r + 1) + " - Cell " + (c + 1); // populate
    }
  }
  // Add the new table as a child of the referenced, pre-existing element on the page
  target.appendChild(tbl);
  return tbl; // return a reference to the new table
}

// ************************************************
//Section to modify table elements

//Selects the html table name
let target1 = document.getElementById("target1");

//Calls create table function 
let newTable1 = makeTable(10,2, target1);  // Make a 5 x 4 table in the first div

//Modiy table elements
let cellToModify1 = newTable1.rows[0].cells[0];
cellToModify1.textContent = "OVERRIDDEN!";
cellToModify1.classList.add("updated");
```

What I want to do is, append the items within my table to display data from the JSON file, such as the data for Alex in one box, and then the data for Tom in another.

Comment: Values can be accessed like `Arrays` and `Objects` in JS, eg. `results[0].name`, but what is your exact goal with the `json`?

Comment: basically I'm trying to select specific elements within my .json and add it into a table which I've created using HTML & javascript

Comment: Yes so you can access elements like shown above, maybe use `if/else` for specific ones, and add to table using jQuery `.append()` There are plenty of ways you can find how to do that.

Comment: So at the minute I have a table in JS, with code:
let cellToModify1 = newTable1.rows[0].cells[0];
cellToModify1.textContent = "OVERRIDDEN!";

which selects which specific row and column to edit, now i know I will need to change .textContent, however I don't know what with?

Comment: Can you update your question with the JavaScript code that you have?

Comment: Added ^^ I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: also added some more information

Comment: In `let target1 = document.getElementById("target1");` what is `target1`?

Comment: Updated original question to clarify ^

Comment: Did this make it more clear